# My jQuery .click event is creating an error as it has a click() event within

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have an outer div with two buttons within it.  When the outer div is clicked I would like it to click two buttons inside of it.

When I try to do this I get the following error in the browser console:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This is my code:

```
jQuery( "#boz .wrapper1" ).click(function() {
    jQuery('button.select1', this).click();
    jQuery('button.submit', this).click();
});
```

I've tried using the [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) function in various ways but still the issue persists.

```
jQuery( "#boz .wrapper1" ).click(function( event ) {
        jQuery('button.select1', this).click();
        event.stopPropagation();
        jQuery('button.submit', this).click();
        event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**UPDATE**
Basic Markup is:

```
<div id="boz">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image"><img src="example.jpg" alt="example"></div>
        <div class="desc">Lorem Impsum</div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="other-stuff">Blah Bla Blah</div>
            <button class="select1">Click Me</button>
            <button class="submit">Submit Me</button>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image"><img src="example.jpg" alt="example"></div>
        <div class="desc">Lorem Impsum</div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="other-stuff">Blah Bla Blah</div>
            <button class="select1">Click Me</button>
            <button class="submit">Submit Me</button>                                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image"><img src="example.jpg" alt="example"></div>
        <div class="desc">Lorem Impsum</div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="other-stuff">Blah Bla Blah</div>
            <button class="select1">Click Me</button>
            <button class="submit">Submit Me</button>                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the basic markup of the page?

Comment: Try to add this. `jQuery( 'button.select1, button.submit' ).click(function( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: @epascarello, added some basic markup to the question

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, I tried by putting your code before the click event I had but nothing happens, and no messages in the console

Comment: Well you have an element that you listen for click events on, than you trigger click events inside that element that you are listening for clicks on and than that triggers more clicks and you run out of stack.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried to use the [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method?

```js
jQuery( "#boz .wrapper1" ).click(function( event ) {
    jQuery('button.select1', this).trigger('click');
    jQuery('button.submit', this).trigger('click');
});
```

Another hint could be to add an `event.stopPropagation();` in the buttons click handlers themselves, in order to prevent the bubbling up to the parent div.

At last, should the actual parent div be the one that fetch the event? You could always use another div doing the work, and have it positioned as expected using css properties.

Comment: yes I tried that.  I get the same error message with it `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stopPropagation` inside the click handlers for the buttons. Because that would stop event from reaching the original div again. If it reaches, it would again trigger the button clicks and so the chain continues and `stack size exceeded` error occurs.

```
jQuery( "#boz .wrapper1" ).click(function( event ) {
        jQuery('button.select1', this).click();
        // event.stopPropagation(); not required here
        jQuery('button.submit', this).click();
        // event.stopPropagation(); not required here
});

jQuery('button.select1').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); // need to use it here
});//click

jQuery('button.submit').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); // need to use it here
});//click
```

Comment: thanks but it did not work either.  I need the buttons to be clicked but only once.  The `e.stopPropagation()` seems to stop them from being clicked at all

Comment: what happens on the clicks of the buttons? Is there any js code that is bound to click event? If there is, please share that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this,

```
jQuery( "#boz .wrapper1" ).click(function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery('button.select1, button.submit').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I took a different approach which got rid of error.  Rather than set the click event on a single outer element I set it on several inner elements.

```
jQuery( ".wrapper > .image, .wrapper > .desc, .wrapper .other-stuff" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().find("span.choose").click();
    jQuery(this).parent().find("button.submit").click();
});
jQuery( ".wrapper .select1").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().find("button.submit").click();
});
```